# Reactjs onClick on a dynamic component not invoked as expected

Tags: reactjs, events, onclick

Here's App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ValidationComponent from './ValidationComponent/ValidationComponent';
import CharComponent from './CharComponent/CharComponent';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    word: '',
    wordlength: 0
  }

  wordLengthHandler = (event) => {
    let wordlength = event.target.value.length;
    let word = event.target.value;

    this.setState({
      word: word,
      wordlength: wordlength
    })
  }

  onClickCharComponentHandler = (e, index) => {
    {/*when clicked hide a charcomponent. delete the char from word.*/}
    const wordarr = this.state.word.split('');
    wordarr.splice(index,1);
    const word = wordarr.join('');
    this.setState({
      word: word
    });
  }

  render() {
    {/*each character as an array element*/}
    const wordarr = this.state.word.split('');
    {/*render each character into charcomponent*/}
    const charcomponents = wordarr.map(
      (c, index) => { return <CharComponent ch={c}  click={(e, index)=>this.onClickCharComponentHandler} /> });


    return (
    <div className="App">
        {/* my answer */}
        <input onChange={(event) => this.wordLengthHandler(event)} value={this.state.word} />
        <p>{this.state.wordlength}</p>
        <ValidationComponent wordlength={this.state.wordlength} />
        {charcomponents}

        <ol>
          <li>Create an input field (in App component) with a change listener which outputs the length of the entered text below it (e.g. in a paragraph).</li>
          <li>Create a new component (=> ValidationComponent) which receives the text length as a prop</li>
          <li>Inside the ValidationComponent, either output "Text too short" or "Text long enough" depending on the text length (e.g. take 5 as a minimum length)</li>
          <li>Create another component (=> CharComponent) and style it as an inline box (=> display: inline-block, padding: 16px, text-align: center, margin: 16px, border: 1px solid black).</li>
          <li>Render a list of CharComponents where each CharComponent receives a different letter of the entered text (in the initial input field) as a prop.</li>
          <li>When you click a CharComponent, it should be removed from the entered text.</li>
        </ol>
        <p>Hint: Keep in mind that JavaScript strings are basically arrays!</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

When a CharComponent is clicked, this should invoke onClickCharComponentHandler which will remove the character and update state.word with the character removed.

Here's CharComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class CharComponent extends Component
{
    render() 
    {
        const style={
            display: 'inline-block', padding: '16px', textAlign: 'center', margin: '16px', border: '1px solid black'
        }
        return <div style={style} onClick={this.props.click}>{this.props.ch}</div>
    }

}

export default CharComponent;
```

Lastly, here's ValidationComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ValidationComponent extends Component
{
    render() 
    {
        return <p>{this.props.wordlength>=5?'Text long enough':'Text too short'}</p>
    }
}

export default ValidationComponent;
```

Right now, when I click on a rendered CharComponent nothing happens, as if onClick doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is you are actually not calling the function.
You have 2 options to call the function:

```
const charcomponents = wordarr.map(
      (c, index) => { return <CharComponent ch={c}  onClick={(e, index)=>this.onClickCharComponentHandler(e, index)} /> });

const charcomponents = wordarr.map(
      (c, index) => { return <CharComponent ch={c}  onClick={this.onClickCharComponentHandler} /> });
```

Comment: Also it's `onClick` not `click`